# Граф. Поиск максимального количества путей для каждой вершины

Tags: алгоритм, графы

Необходимо посчитать максимальное количество путей для каждой вершины до помеченных вершин, при условии, что все пути для одной вершины проходят через разные вершины (не пересекаются), не считая ее саму и конечную.

Есть ли подобная реализация, так же интересует частный случай, не для всего графа, а только для одной вершины. И еще одно возможное допущение, доказать что существует хотя бы 2 пути по разным вершинам.

Для всех допущений:
Необходимо перебором по-очереди выкидывать каждую вершину и рекурсивно, через смежные вершины искать помеченную точку. Если в какой-то итерации точка не будет найдена, значит 2х путей нет. Вроде так.

Comment: Количество вариантов наборов непересекающихся путей может быть более одного. При этом разные варианты могут включать разное количество путей. Т.е. задача может иметь несколько решений. Простейший вариант: граф 1-2,1-3,2-3,2-4,3-4. Начало - 1, конец - 4. Возможен вариант с 2 путями 1-2-4 и 1-3-4, и вариант с 1 путём 1-2-3-4. Тебя устроит решение "1 или 2"?

Comment: Вы хотели сказать, конец 4, я полагаю. Нужно найти максимальное кол-во путей. Для вершины 1 кол-во путей 2.

Comment: `Нужно найти максимальное кол-во путей` Добавьте это в вопрос, да пожирнее...

Comment: А ещё кажется мне, что в общем случае задачка-то переборная...

Comment: Для начала, хотя бы доказать, что есть 2 таких пути. Сейчас в голову что-то ничего не приходит.

Comment: что-то мне кажется что задача np-полная. Она не проще чем поиск гамильтонова цикла.

Comment: Для доказательства существования 2 путей достаточно убедиться, что невозможно выбросить из графа одно ребро (если в путях запрещены общие рёбра) или одну вершину (если запрещены общие вершины) так, чтобы он распался на 2 несвязанных, причём начало и конец находятся в разных подграфах.

Comment: @Akina а тут учитывается, что не в путях не может быть общих вершин? Уже поправили, спасибо!

Comment: @Akina
граф: 1-2, 2-3, 2-4
ищем пути от 1 к 4
выкидываем 3, получаем что 1 и 4 в находятся в одном связном графе. Т.е. с ваших слов есть 2 пути. Хотя путь только один 1-2-4
Тут я ошибся, не выполнил условие - чтобы он распался на 2 несвязных.

Тогда как быть, сначала находить любой путь от 1 до 4 и из него выкидывать вершину?

Comment: или не ошибся...

Comment: Получается необходимо перебором по-очереди выкидывать каждую вершину и рекурсивно, через смежные вершины искать помеченную точку. Если в какой-то итерации точка не будет найдена, значит 2х путей нет. Вроде так.

Comment: @Leonid Самое важное Вы пропустили: `причём начало и конец находятся в разных подграфах`. Чтобы и оно выполнялось - надо выбросить вершину 2. И коли такое выбрасывание есть - двух путей не видать...

Comment: @Akina 
`и рекурсивно, через смежные вершины искать помеченную точку`
Это то же что и `причём начало и конец находятся в разных подграфах` только другими словами, так что не пропустил.
Должно работать, спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Только вот сложность получается порядка O(n^2) думаю для одной вершины кардинально упростить не получится. А вот при поиске для всех вершин можно подумать.